# Why does React/redux state reset on refresh?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, immutable.js

When i login, everything works fine but the moment i hit refresh or navigate somewhere else, the state gets reset. Any idea why? I want to be able to reference the user from the state and get info like name etc and use it inside components. But it only works right after i login and then it will reset.

also, why do i have to use .get in mapstatetoprops? If not i get a Map object. is it because of IMMUTABLE.JS?

Here's my app.js file

```
/**
 * app.js
 *
 * This is the entry file for the application, only setup and boilerplate
 * code.
 */

// Needed for redux-saga es6 generator support
import '@babel/polyfill';

// Import all the third party stuff
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'connected-react-router/immutable';
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';
import FontFaceObserver from 'fontfaceobserver';
import history from 'utils/history';
import 'sanitize.css/sanitize.css';

// Import root app
import App from 'containers/App';

import './styles/layout/base.scss';

// Import Language Provider
import LanguageProvider from 'containers/LanguageProvider';

import { setCurrentUser, logoutUser } from './redux/actions/authActions';
import setAuthToken from './utils/setAuthToken';

// Load the favicon and the .htaccess file
import '!file-loader?name=[name].[ext]!../public/favicons/favicon.ico'; // eslint-disable-line
import 'file-loader?name=.htaccess!./.htaccess'; // eslint-disable-line

import configureStore from './redux/configureStore';

// Import i18n messages
import { translationMessages } from './i18n';

// Check for token to keep user logged in
if (localStorage.jwtToken) {
  // Set auth token header auth
  const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.jwtToken);
  setAuthToken(token);

  // Decode token and get user info and exp
  const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
  console.log(decoded);

  // Set user and isAuthenticated
  setCurrentUser(decoded);
  // Check for expired token
  const currentTime = Date.now() / 1000; // to get in milliseconds
  if (decoded.exp < currentTime) {
    // Logout user
    logoutUser();

    // Redirect to login
    window.location.href = './';
  }
}

// Observe loading of Open Sans (to remove open sans, remove the <link> tag in
// the index.html file and this observer)
const openSansObserver = new FontFaceObserver('Open Sans', {});

// When Open Sans is loaded, add a font-family using Open Sans to the body
openSansObserver.load().then(() => {
  document.body.classList.add('fontLoaded');
});

// Create redux store with history
const initialState = {};
const store = configureStore(initialState, history);
const MOUNT_NODE = document.getElementById('app');

const render = messages => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <LanguageProvider messages={messages}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
          <App />
        </ConnectedRouter>
      </LanguageProvider>
    </Provider>,
    MOUNT_NODE,
  );
};

if (module.hot) {
  // Hot reloadable React components and translation json files
  // modules.hot.accept does not accept dynamic dependencies,
  // have to be constants at compile-time
  module.hot.accept(['./i18n', 'containers/App'], () => {
    ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(MOUNT_NODE);
    render(translationMessages);
  });
}

// Chunked polyfill for browsers without Intl support
if (!window.Intl) {
  new Promise(resolve => {
    resolve(import('intl'));
  })
    .then(() =>
      Promise.all([import('intl/locale-data/jsonp/en.js'), import('intl/locale-data/jsonp/de.js')]),
    ) // eslint-disable-line prettier/prettier
    .then(() => render(translationMessages))
    .catch(err => {
      throw err;
    });
} else {
  render(translationMessages);
}
// Install ServiceWorker and AppCache in the end since
// it's not most important operation and if main code fails,
// we do not want it installed
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  require('offline-plugin/runtime').install(); // eslint-disable-line global-require
}
```

index.js inside app folder

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import NotFound from 'containers/Pages/Standalone/NotFoundDedicated';
import Auth from './Auth';
import Application from './Application';
import ThemeWrapper, { AppContext } from './ThemeWrapper';
import { Login } from '../pageListAsync';
import PrivateRoute from './PrivateRoute';

const isLoggedIn = localStorage.getItem('jwtToken') !== null ? true : false;

window.__MUI_USE_NEXT_TYPOGRAPHY_VARIANTS__ = true;
console.log(localStorage);
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ThemeWrapper>
        <AppContext.Consumer>
          {changeMode => (
            <Switch>
              <Route path="/" exact component={Login} />
              <PrivateRoute isLoggedIn={isLoggedIn} exact path="/app" component={Application} />
              <Route
                path="/app"
                render={props => <Application {...props} changeMode={changeMode} />}
              />
              <Route component={Auth} />
              <Route component={NotFound} />
            </Switch>
          )}
        </AppContext.Consumer>
      </ThemeWrapper>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

authactions.js that will setcurrentuser but it only happens once it seems and not again once i reload.

```
import axios from 'axios';
import jwt_decode from 'jwt-decode';
import setAuthToken from '../../utils/setAuthToken';

import { GET_ERRORS, SET_CURRENT_USER, USER_LOADING } from '../constants/authConstants';

// Login - get user token
export const loginUser = userData => dispatch => {
  axios
    .post('/api/total/users/login', userData)
    .then(res => {
      // Save to localStorage

      // Set token to localStorage
      const { token } = res.data;
      localStorage.setItem('jwtToken', JSON.stringify(token));
      // Set token to Auth header
      setAuthToken(token);
      // Decode token to get user data
      const decoded = jwt_decode(token);
      // Set current user
      dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded));
      console.log('logged');
    })
    .catch(err =>
      dispatch({
        type: GET_ERRORS,
        payload: err.response.data,
      }),
    );
};

// Set logged in user
export const setCurrentUser = decoded => {
  return {
    type: SET_CURRENT_USER,
    payload: decoded,
  };
};

// User loading
export const setUserLoading = () => {
  return {
    type: USER_LOADING,
  };
};

// Log user out
export const logoutUser = history => dispatch => {
  // Remove token from local storage
  localStorage.removeItem('jwtToken);
  // Remove auth header for future requests
  setAuthToken(false);
  // Set current user to empty object {} which will set isAuthenticated to false
  dispatch(setCurrentUser({}));

  // history.push('/app');
};
```

**EDIT: When i look at redux devtools i see that the IF block does run every time it is refreshed, but the correct state doesn't seem to be passed on to the other components. The other components get the correct state the first time (isAuthenticated: true) but once i refresh, they go back to false. In redux devtools i see this every time i refresh.**

[image]

main reducer

```
/**
 * Combine all reducers in this file and export the combined reducers.
 */

import { reducer as form } from 'redux-form/immutable';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux-immutable';
import { connectRouter } from 'connected-react-router/immutable';
import history from 'utils/history';

import languageProviderReducer from 'containers/LanguageProvider/reducer';
import uiReducer from './modules/ui';
import initval from './modules/initForm';
import login from './modules/login';
import treeTable from '../containers/Tables/reducers/treeTbReducer';
import crudTable from '../containers/Tables/reducers/crudTbReducer';
import crudTableForm from '../containers/Tables/reducers/crudTbFrmReducer';
import ecommerce from '../containers/SampleApps/Ecommerce/reducers/ecommerceReducer';
import contact from '../containers/SampleApps/Contact/reducers/contactReducer';
import chat from '../containers/SampleApps/Chat/reducers/chatReducer';
import email from '../containers/SampleApps/Email/reducers/emailReducer';
import calendar from '../containers/SampleApps/Calendar/reducers/calendarReducer';
import socmed from '../containers/SampleApps/Timeline/reducers/timelineReducer';
import taskboard from '../containers/SampleApps/TaskBoard/reducers/taskboardReducer';

/**
 * Branching reducers to use one reducer for many components
 */

function branchReducer(reducerFunction, reducerName) {
  return (state, action) => {
    const { branch } = action;
    const isInitializationCall = state === undefined;
    if (branch !== reducerName && !isInitializationCall) {
      return state;
    }
    return reducerFunction(state, action);
  };
}

/**
 * Merges the main reducer with the router state and dynamically injected reducers
 */
export default function createReducer(injectedReducers = {}) {
  const rootReducer = combineReducers({
    form,
    ui: uiReducer,
    initval,
    login,
    socmed,
    calendar,
    ecommerce,
    contact,
    chat,
    email,
    taskboard,
    treeTableArrow: branchReducer(treeTable, 'treeTableArrow'),
    treeTablePM: branchReducer(treeTable, 'treeTablePM'),
    crudTableDemo: branchReducer(crudTable, 'crudTableDemo'),
    crudTableForm,
    crudTbFrmDemo: branchReducer(crudTableForm, 'crudTbFrmDemo'),
    language: languageProviderReducer,
    router: connectRouter(history),
    ...injectedReducers,
  });

  // Wrap the root reducer and return a new root reducer with router state
  const mergeWithRouterState = connectRouter(history);
  return mergeWithRouterState(rootReducer);
}
```

createStore.js

```
/**
 * Create the store with dynamic reducers
 */

import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import { routerMiddleware } from 'connected-react-router';
import { fromJS } from 'immutable';
import createSagaMiddleware from 'redux-saga';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

import createReducer from './reducers';

export default function configureStore(initialState = {}, history) {
  let composeEnhancers = compose;
  const reduxSagaMonitorOptions = {};

  // If Redux Dev Tools and Saga Dev Tools Extensions are installed, enable them
  /* istanbul ignore next */
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production' && typeof window === 'object') {
    /* eslint-disable no-underscore-dangle */
    if (window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__) {
      composeEnhancers = window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__({ trace: true });
    }

    // NOTE: Uncomment the code below to restore support for Redux Saga
    // Dev Tools once it supports redux-saga version 1.x.x
    if (window.__SAGA_MONITOR_EXTENSION__)
      reduxSagaMonitorOptions = {
        sagaMonitor: window.__SAGA_MONITOR_EXTENSION__,
      };
    /* eslint-enable */
  }

  const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware(reduxSagaMonitorOptions);

  // Create the store with two middlewares
  // 1. sagaMiddleware: Makes redux-sagas work
  // 2. routerMiddleware: Syncs the location/URL path to the state
  const middleware = [thunk];
  const middlewares = [...middleware, sagaMiddleware, routerMiddleware(history)];

  const enhancers = [applyMiddleware(...middlewares)];

  const store = createStore(createReducer(), fromJS(initialState), composeEnhancers(...enhancers));

  // Extensions
  store.runSaga = sagaMiddleware.run;
  store.injectedReducers = {}; // Reducer registry
  store.injectedSagas = {}; // Saga registry

  // Make reducers hot reloadable, see http://mxs.is/googmo
  /* istanbul ignore next */
  if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept('./reducers', () => {
      store.replaceReducer(createReducer(store.injectedReducers));
    });
  }

  return store;
}
```

the main app file

```
import React from 'react';
import { Switch, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import NotFound from 'containers/Pages/Standalone/NotFoundDedicated';
import jwtDecode from 'jwt-decode';
import configureStore from '../../redux/configureStore';
import { setCurrentUser, logoutUser } from '../../redux/actions/authActions';
import setAuthToken from '../../utils/setAuthToken';
import Auth from './Auth';
import Application from './Application';
import ThemeWrapper, { AppContext } from './ThemeWrapper';
import { PrivateRoute } from './PrivateRoute';

window.__MUI_USE_NEXT_TYPOGRAPHY_VARIANTS__ = true;
const initialState = {};

const store = configureStore(initialState);
const auth = localStorage.jwtToken ? true : false;
// Check for token to keep user logged in
if (localStorage.jwtToken) {
  // Set auth token header auth
  const token = JSON.parse(localStorage.jwtToken);
  setAuthToken(token);

  // Decode token and get user info and exp
  const decoded = jwtDecode(token);

  // Set user and isAuthenticated
  store.dispatch(setCurrentUser(decoded));
  // Check for expired token
  const currentTime = Date.now() / 1000; // to get in milliseconds
  if (decoded.exp < currentTime) {
    // Logout user
    logoutUser();

    // Redirect to login
    window.location.href = './';
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: '',
      errors: {},
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ThemeWrapper>
        <AppContext.Consumer>
          {changeMode => (
            <Switch>
              {/* <Route path="/" exact component={Login} /> */}
              <PrivateRoute
                path="/app"
                auth={auth}
                component={props => <Application {...props} changeMode={changeMode} />}
              />
              <Route component={Auth} />
              <Route component={NotFound} />
            </Switch>
          )}
        </AppContext.Consumer>
      </ThemeWrapper>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

infectreducer

```
import React from 'react';
import hoistNonReactStatics from 'hoist-non-react-statics';
import { ReactReduxContext } from 'react-redux';

import getInjectors from './reducerInjectors';

/**
 * Dynamically injects a reducer
 *
 * @param {string} key A key of the reducer
 * @param {function} reducer A reducer that will be injected
 *
 */
export default ({ key, reducer }) => WrappedComponent => {
  class ReducerInjector extends React.Component {
    static WrappedComponent = WrappedComponent;

    static contextType = ReactReduxContext;

    static displayName = `withReducer(${WrappedComponent.displayName ||
      WrappedComponent.name ||
      'Component'})`;

    constructor(props, context) {
      super(props, context);

      getInjectors(context.store).injectReducer(key, reducer);
    }

    render() {
      return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
    }
  }

  return hoistNonReactStatics(ReducerInjector, WrappedComponent);
};

const useInjectReducer = ({ key, reducer }) => {
  const context = React.useContext(ReactReduxContext);
  React.useEffect(() => {
    getInjectors(context.store).injectReducer(key, reducer);
  }, []);
};

export { useInjectReducer };
```

reducerinjector

```
import invariant from 'invariant';
import { isEmpty, isFunction, isString } from 'lodash';

import checkStore from './checkStore';
import createReducer from '../redux/reducers';

export function injectReducerFactory(store, isValid) {
  return function injectReducer(key, reducer) {
    if (!isValid) checkStore(store);

    invariant(
      isString(key) && !isEmpty(key) && isFunction(reducer),
      '(app/utils...) injectReducer: Expected `reducer` to be a reducer function',
    );

    // Check `store.injectedReducers[key] === reducer` for hot reloading when a key is the same but a reducer is different
    if (
      Reflect.has(store.injectedReducers, key)
      && store.injectedReducers[key] === reducer
    ) return;

    store.injectedReducers[key] = reducer; // eslint-disable-line no-param-reassign
    store.replaceReducer(createReducer(store.injectedReducers));
  };
}

export default function getInjectors(store) {
  checkStore(store);

  return {
    injectReducer: injectReducerFactory(store, true),
  };
}
```

Comment: You can use [redux-persist](https://github.com/rt2zz/redux-persist) to keep the state after refresh. Maybe helps.

Comment: The state of an application is stored in a nested object within the store. So when you refresh a page, since the app reloads the memory is cleared and hence the object is reset to the initial value.

Comment: Shouldn't the if statement re-run every time the page is refreshed and the state updated?

Answer (score 1):

Use persistedState. This is index.js file example

```
function saveToLocalStorage(state) {
  try {
    const serializedState = JSON.stringify(state)
    localStorage.setItem('state', serializedState)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
  }
}

function loadFromLocalStorage() {
  try {
    const serializedState = localStorage.getItem('state');
    if (serializedState === null) return undefined;
    return JSON.parse(serializedState)
  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err)
    return undefined;
  }
}

const persistedState = loadFromLocalStorage();

const sagaMiddleware = createSagaMiddleware();
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  persistedState,
  applyMiddleware(logger, sagaMiddleware))
sagaMiddleware.run(watchLoadData);

store.subscribe(() => saveToLocalStorage(store.getState()))

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <App />
    </Provider>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Comment: Shouldn't the if statement re-run every time the page is refreshed and the state updated?

Comment: actually this seem to work, but why when i console.log(localStorage.state) i get this "{\"contact\":{\"formValues\":{},\"keywordValue\":\"\",\"avatarInit\":\"\",\"showMobileDetail\":false,\"notifMsg\":\"\",\"selectedId\":\"\",\"openFrm\":false,\"selectedIndex\":0,\"contactList\":[]},\"ecommerce\":"  

How do i return a useable format?

Comment: nevermind, i got it JSON.parse. The state still get reset though. Even when i look at localstorage, after i reload the page the state is reset

Comment: in reducer do something like this
`const initialState = {
    id: localStorage.getItem('id'),
    email: localStorage.getItem('email'),
    name: localStorage.getItem('name'),
    token: localStorage.getItem('token'),
    authStatus: localStorage.getItem('authStatus'),
    errorMessage: ''
}`

Comment: Makes all values null when i do this

Comment: Are u saving to local storage ur state? In index.js this line is saving it`store.subscribe(() => saveToLocalStorage(store.getState()))`. Open dev tools -> application -> local storage and check ur data

Comment: yes. 

`// Create redux store with history
const initialState = {};
const store = configureStore(initialState, history, persistedState);
const MOUNT_NODE = document.getElementById('app');

store.subscribe(() => saveToLocalStorage(store.getState()));

const render = messages => {
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Provider store={store}>
      <LanguageProvider messages={messages}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
          <App />
        </ConnectedRouter>
      </LanguageProvider>
    </Provider>,
    MOUNT_NODE,
  );
};`

Comment: Show me your reducer initial state

Comment: i added the code for 5 more files in my initial post,  the main reducers file, createstore file, the main app file, injectreducer.js and reducerinjector.js

Comment: so the code you gave me does save state to localstorage but when i refresh, it resets state and also updates the localstorage state so it resets both