# In redux how to make the data non volatile

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am using redux So i have the user input their credentials and login after login I update the state but if the page refresh the data of state in lost which should not be done how can I make it non volatile the second thing I want some ui to not display If the user logged in i have google about it but the imports they are telling [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43230194/how-to-use-redirect-in-version-5-of-react-router-dom-of-reactjs) are not working anymore

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does React/redux state reset on refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62847854/why-does-react-redux-state-reset-on-refresh)

Comment: @sarangkkl the keyword you're looking for is "persist". You want to persist the redux store. There are options like localStorage (a feature of every modern browser) to do this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to persist redux state in the easiest way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49330546/how-to-persist-redux-state-in-the-easiest-way)

Answer (score 1):

```
Maybe u can wrap the content u don't want to render inside Curly Braces and do a 
check if you're Condition is true or false for example:
```

```
{!isNotLoggedIn ? // content you want to show : return null }
```

It should only display the content when the User is Not Logged in,
otherwise it
returns nothing.
And for the other Problem, i would try to save the State in the
localStorage or Session Storage. Or otherwise send it to a server.